# Int comparison with array in for loop to get no duplicate value

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, android-activity

I am trying to make sure that the answer generated will not be duplicated in a maths app on Android. Here is the code I have:
If I initialise an array of person objects with this data

```
private int answer = 0, operator = 0, operand1 = 0, operand2 = 0;
private Random random;
private int AnswerCounter = 0;
private int[] numberList {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
private int[] ans =new int[50];
private String[] operators = {"+", "-", "x", "/"};
```

Below is the method I used for randomization and double checking the duplicate answers. ans[] doesn't seem to be working...

It is probably a really stupid logic problem but I have been pulling my hair out over here not being able to figure this out. When I run the program, the answer still exceed 30 and there are still repeated answer.

Thanks for looking :)

```
private void chooseQuestion(){//if answer is repeated, operands and operators should be randomized again.

        operator = random.nextInt(operators.length);
        //choose operands
        operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
        operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);

        //checks for operators
        if(operator==0){//ADD_OPERATOR
            answer = operand1+operand2;

            if(AnswerCounter==0){//first ans
                while(answer>30){
                    operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    answer = operand1+operand2;
                }
            }

            else{//from the 2nd ans onwards
                for (int x=0; x<(AnswerCounter);x++){
                    while((answer==ans[x])||(answer>30)){
                        //choose operands
                        operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                        operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                        answer = operand1+operand2;
                    }
                }
            }
          ans[AnswerCounter] = answer;
          AnswerCounter++;//increase so that the array num can increase 
        }
        else if(operator==1){ //SUBTRACT_OPERATOR
            answer = operand1-operand2;

            if(AnswerCounter==0){//first ans
                while((operand2>operand1)||answer>30){//no negative answer allowed, answer cannot be above 30
                    operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    answer = operand1-operand2;
                }
            }

            else{//from the 2nd ans onwards
                for (int x=0; x<(AnswerCounter);x++){
                    while((operand2>operand1)||answer==ans[x]||(answer>30)){
                        //choose operands
                        operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                        operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                        answer = operand1+operand2;
                    }
                    }

            }
            answer = operand1-operand2;
            ans[AnswerCounter] = answer;
            AnswerCounter++;//increase so that the array num can increase
            }
        else if(operator==2){ //MULTIPLY_OPERATOR
            /*
            while(operand1>12||operand2>12){
                operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
            }
            //while(operand2>13){
                //operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
            //}
            */
            answer = operand1*operand2;

            if(AnswerCounter==0){//first ans
                while(answer>30){
                    operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    answer = operand1+operand2;
                }
            }
            else{//from the 2nd ans onwards
                for (int x=0; x<(AnswerCounter);x++){
                    while((operand1>12||operand2>12)||answer==ans[x]||(answer>30)){
                    //choose operands
                    operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    answer = operand1*operand2;
                }
                }
            }
            answer = operand1*operand2;
            ans[AnswerCounter] = answer;
            AnswerCounter++;//increase so that the array num can increase
        }
        else if(operator==3){ //DIVIDE_OPERATOR
            /*
            //whole numbers only
            while((((double)operand1/(double)operand2)%1 > 0) 
                    || (operand1==operand2)||(operand1==0)||(operand2==0)){
                operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
            }
            */

            //answer = operand1/operand2;// not sure if this is an error
            if(AnswerCounter==0){//first ans
                while((((double)operand1/(double)operand2)%1 > 0)||(operand1==operand2)||(operand1==0)||answer>30){
                    operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    answer = operand1/operand2;
                }
            }

            else{//from the 2nd ans onwards
            for (int x=0; x<(AnswerCounter);x++){

                while((((double)operand1/(double)operand2)%1 > 0) || (operand1==operand2)||(operand1==0)||answer==ans[x]||(answer>30)){
                    //choose operands
                    operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    answer = operand1/operand2;

                    try {//||(operand2==0)
                        operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                        operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                        answer = operand1/operand2;
                        } catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
                            operand2+=1;
                        }

                }

            }
            answer = operand1/operand2;
            ans[AnswerCounter] = answer;
            AnswerCounter++;//increase so that the array num can increase
        }

        }
```

Comment: Where is the actual problem?

Comment: What occurs when your run your program? What does ans become.

Comment: while loop doesn't seem to be working as answer has been repeated before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose AnswerCounter is 3, and ans[] contains [2, 4, 6], and then the next operator comes up as 0, so add.  Also operand1 as 5 and operand2 is 1.  So, the code cones to :

```
            for (int x=0; x<(AnswerCounter);x++){
                while((answer==ans[x])||(answer>30)){
                    //choose operands
                    operand1 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    operand2 = random.nextInt(numberList.length);
                    answer = operand1+operand2;
                }
            }
```

X = 0 and 1 passesOK, but then it comes to x==2, and the condition fails because answer (6) == ans[x] so it has to pick another number.  Maybe this time it chooses both operand1 and operand2 as 2.  This time answer==4, which doesn't equal ans[x], so the condition passes and the loop completes, so ans[] becomes [2,4,6,4].

To fix this think along the following lines :  to check that a value is not a duplicate is a logical "chunk" or "unit" of work - eg. You could have a function "isNotDuplicate".  How would you arrange your code so that this function would be called from just ONE spot?

Comment: I tried using Arrays.asList(...).contains(...) , but the while doesn't seem to work

Comment: The while in the snippet above?  That's the point - the checking for duplicates can't be inside that 'for' loop in the snippet.  In fact, you have four operations - add,subtract,etc.  the checking for duplicates is something that has to happen REGARDLESS of which operation was chosen (after each 'answer' has been picked).  So, you need something like "pick answer based on operation" followed by "is answer a duplicate?  If so, loop back to pick another answer"

Comment: When I run my program , the while loops doesn't seem to be working because some of the equation that were formed , the answer is either duplicated or exceed 30

Comment: You're running into trouble because I guess you're still having your loops try to do more than one thing, so try this to separate the functionality clearly :  Split your code into three functions - the main has the controlling loop, a "generateAnAnswer()" that returns an 'answer' less than 30, and an 'isDuplicate()' that returns true/false.  'generateAnAnswer' is NOT to check for duplicates, and 'isDuplicate' is NOT to re-calculate 'answer'.  The main function simply loops depending on what isDuplicate() returns.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I tried splitting the functions then I realised that Arrays.asList(...).contains(...) doesn't work because I have to change it from int [] ans into Integer[] (it was explained in stackoverflow.com/questions/18080269/…) , which I tried and still not able to do it. Is it possible to store value into Object ?

Comment: So don't use 'Arrays.asList' :). Choose a storage structure (either int[], or some List<Integer>), and then stick with it.  Having to repeatedly convert it into something else is a bad code smell.  (and 'for' loops iterating across int[] is fine - you don't HAVE to use 'contains()').  Whichever storage structure you choose will not change the behaviour of those three methods I suggested (merely their implementation).  Your bug was caused by single bits of code doing too much (checking for duplicates AND less than 30) leading to repetition - lookup "separation of concerns" and "DRY principle"

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I still didn't manage to use the DRY principle. But the WET principle work in my case :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), which doesn't allow duplicate elements, to store the answers. So if you try adding an answer to the set and it returns false, you know it was a duplicate.